# Can't grant MySQL privileges to Debian system maintenance user

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, permissions

I have a dedicated Debian 7 server running multiple websites with MySQL as the database server. When I tried to install the latest updates, MySQL couldn't be updated because the server failed to stop.

I found someone with similar symptoms in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/268053/debian-cant-stop-mysql-permissions

The answers to the above question suggest granting full privileges on all databases to `'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'`, but when I try to grant the privileges I get an access denied error.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Another weird thing is I now have two root users in my `mysql.user` table. Is this normal or could this be related to my problem? The `localhost.localdomain` one doesn't even have a password hash. I also have one user for each site I run but I left them out for clarity.

```
+-----------------------+------------------+
| Host                  | User             |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| localhost             | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost             | root             |
| localhost.localdomain | root             |
+-----------------------+------------------+
```

**Edit:** Running `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` says this:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server is broken or not fully installed
```

Searching by that error led me to a [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998260) suggesting there may be older packages messing things up, but to me it looks like that's not the case here:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
dovecot-mysql                                   install
libdbd-mysql-perl                               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64                          install
mysql-client-5.5                                install
mysql-common                                    install
mysql-server                                    install
mysql-server-5.5                                install
mysql-server-core-5.5                           install
php5-mysql                                      install
```

Comment: What happens if you `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`?

Comment: @Xyon: It says `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server is broken or not fully installed`. Doesn't sound too nice.

Comment: Please run this query : `select count(1) ColumnCount from information_schema.columns where table_schema='mysql' and table_name='user';` What is the ColumnCount ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: 37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three(3) posts in the StackExchange that quickly explain the root cause

- `Apr 24, 2014` : [mysql: Restore All privileges to admin user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23276684/491757)
- `Aug 07, 2013` : [MySQL - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user : permission issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47700/877)
- `May 01, 2013` : [Can I find out what version of MySQL from the data files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41338/can-i-find-out-what-version-of-mysql-from-the-data-files/41350#41350)

## ROOT CAUSE

- You have 37 columns in `mysql.user`. That's OK for MySQL 5.0
- You are running MySQL 5.5. You are supposed to have 42 columns.

## SUGGESTION

You will have to run MySQL command

```
# mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables
```

Keep in mind that you are leaping two versions of MySQL. Backup the `mysql.user` table before doing so

## UPDATE 2015-02-10 10:59 EST

Based on [your comment](https://superuser.com/questions/874568/cant-grant-mysql-privileges-to-debian-system-maintenance-user/875719#comment1166738_875719), I can only suggest one thing: Refer to my post [Any known issues upgrading from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.21? under the section "ISSUE #1 : Upgrade Path"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80503/877) on how to upgrade two versions of MySQL.

## UPDATE 2015-02-11 12:26 EST

Here is your situation

- You have a `mysql.user` that is MySQL 5.0 compliant
- You have to get `mysql.user` upgraded to work with MySQL 5.5

I have a crazy idea: Add the missing 5 columns by hand

In my DBA StackExchange post [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441), I display all the columns in the `mysql.user` table from MySQL 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0 and 4.x.

From those displays, we will do the following:

- Make a backup of mysql.user beforehand as mysql.user_backup
- Construct `mysql.user` to have the same columns as MySQL 5.5, adding the five(5) missing colunms.
- Make sure the columns are in the same order
- Fill in the missing privs for root users with `Y`
- Deploy new privs

**Steps to repair `mysql.user`**

```
CREATE TABLE mysql.user_backup LIKE mysql.user;
INSERT INTO mysql.user_backup SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
    ADD Event_priv enum('N','Y') DEFAULT 'N' AFTER Create_user_priv;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
    ADD Trigger_priv enum('N','Y') DEFAULT 'N' AFTER Event_priv;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
    ADD Create_tablespace_priv enum('N','Y') DEFAULT 'N' AFTER Trigger_priv;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
   ADD plugin CHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL AFTER max_user_connections;
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
    ADD authentication_string text DEFAULT 'N' AFTER plugin;
UPDATE mysql.user SET
    Event_priv='Y',
    Trigger_priv='Y',
    Create_tablespace_priv ='Y'
WHERE user='root' and host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you want to revert it, you can do this

```
RENAME TABLE mysql.user TO mysql.user_old,mysql.user_backup TO mysql.user;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried that but...
`xxx@yyy:~$ sudo mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables`  
`Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql`  
`The --upgrade-system-tables option was used, databases won't be touched.`  
`FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed`

Comment: Finally got it working with your instructions, many thanks! `TEXT` columns don't apparently accept defaults so I left the `DEFAULT 'N'` part out but MySQL didn't seem to mind. After that I could grant the correct privileges and was finally able to upgrade the MySQL binaries.